# Best strategy to win a card game

Tags: game-theory, card-games

> The contest consists of a series of matches of psychological jujitsu between bots. In each match, 2 bots face off for N = 1024 turns. At the beginning of a match, each bot receives 1024 cards numbered from 0 to 1023. In each turn, both bots fight for a number of points by playing a card, so that the one who plays the highest card wins the points. In case both play the same card, neither of them wins the points. Regardless of the outcome of the turn (even in case of a tie), both cards are discarded, so each bot must play each number from 0 to 1023 exactly once in the match. The number of points contested in each turn starts at 0 and increases by 1 until the last turn, in which 1023 points are contested.

Is there a strategy that guarantees winning?

Comment: I would suggest-without having an answer-starting by reducing $N$. Say try it with $N=4$ and see if a strategy can be discerned.

Comment: How could there be a strategy that guarantees winning in a symmetric game? The usual question to ask about such a game would be, what are the Nash equilibria?

Comment: If there was a guarantee of player 1 winning, the same strategy would guarantee 2 winning. The game is symmetrical.

Comment: With $N=13$, this is very similar to the game of [Goofspiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goofspiel).